# echo to file loop in bash script

Tags: bash, solaris, ksh

say that i am trying to do a echo `TZ=GMT-24 date +%Y%m%d` >> echoed.

This is in solaris.

Now, i would like to do a loop that reads a specific number of days and echoes with GMT-24/GMT-48 etc... until the number of days ends... this is a 5 times loop.... basicly from monday to friday. i will set this script on crontab that will run in one day and generates that echo output to a file so other script that i already have created can check those dates and work with them.

thanks in advance

Comment: And your question is?  You description is ambiguous.  You say that you read "a specific number of days" (where from?) but then you say that it is a 5 times loop.  Which is it, fixed or variable?  Which part of writing a loop are you having a problem with?

Answer (score 0):

This is ksh on Solaris 8:

```
$ date +%Y%m%d
20130919
$ for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do TZ=GMT-$(($i * 24)) date +%Y%m%d; done
20130920
20130921
20130922
20130923
20130924
$ for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do TZ=GMT+$(($i * 24)) date +%Y%m%d; done
20130918
20130917
20130916
20130915
20130914
```

To redirect to a file, add `> filename` after the `done` keyword